# How to debug JavaScript program using Nashorn?

Tags: javascript, debugging, nashorn

I need to be able to Debug JS code run by Nashorn i.e:

```
ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = sem.getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval("load (\"src/com/sap/rdl/runjs/file.js\");");
```

Now I need to add a breakpoint in the JS file and be able to step through the lines programmatically (implement a debugger).

I know intelliJ and NetBeans implemented this so it should be possible, yet I cannot find any API in Nashorn that allows stepping and/or mapping of lines or variables.

Any advice/links would be most welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have the same problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791772/debugging-nashorn-revisited . The ide stackoverflow answer I referenced there may be helpful to you.

Comment: @SteveB. your link is dead.

Comment: @planty182: http://web.archive.org/web/20150426130812/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791772/debugging-nashorn-revisited

Answer (score 5):

You can debug your code in Intellij IDEA.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/debugger-for-jdk8s-nashorn-javascript-in-intellij-idea-13-1/

Also, you can try to use askari. It's a prototype that allow you to step through JavaScript code

https://github.com/wickund/nashornexamples/tree/master/askari

Cheers,
Vik

Comment: I need to do it programmatically - meaning i need to write code that does it not use some IDE to do it. We are implementing a debugger so i do need to reinvent the weel here :) any articles/ relevant people contacts would be most welcome

Comment: Nashorn uses the jvmdi API for debugging with additional support provided in Nashorn's Debugger support class.